# Using strtok with various input sizes

Tags: c

So I've been working on some code that doesn't quite run as expected.

The code below should call a help function when only 'h' is typed in, and quit when 'q' is typed in. I can't really understand when is it when I press 'h' it gives an error:

```
printf("\n");
printf("Please input request (h-help, q-quit): ");

fgets(Input, 256, stdin);
char *array[256];
int count = 0;
char *token = strtok(Input, " ");
array[0] = token;
count++;

while(token != NULL)
{
    int i = 1;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    array[i] = token;
    i++;
    count++;
}

if(count == 1)
{
    if(strlen(array[0]) == 2)
    {
        if(array[0] == 'h')
        {
            TRIGhelp();
            return 0;
        }
        if(array[0] == 'q')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: Illegal input!");
    }
}
```

I have used a count variable because larger strings can be input. For example the user can input three numbers, or a string and three numbers, etc.

I have tried using strlen(array[0]) == 1 as well, it still prints out the error message.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings (`-Wall` with gcc/clang) and PAY ATTENTION to them...

Comment: Think about your while loop a little bit. If you declare `i` inside it on every iteration, will it ever change? When you say "it gives an error" what do you mean? Does your program crash or does it just print the error string you have in the program? Based on your code, will count ever be 1, even if the second strtok returns NULL? Do you think `if (array[0][0] == 'h')` might work better?

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/HDNOKc)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here, but I'll concentrate on `strtok` as that is what you are asking about.

You're reading a line from the input with `fgets` but then tokenize only on space characters.  Every line will end with a newline (`\n`) so what do you want to do with it?  Users might also enter tabs and on some systems you might get `\r` characters at the end of the line.  So you probably want

```
token = strtok(Input, " \t\r\n");
```

in order to tokenize on ALL whitespace, not just spaces.

Comment: Hey! I didn't consider the newline and tabs. Thanks a lot! I'm still new to programming in C, can you please point out what some other problems are? I've fixed the while loop by putting the declaration before it, and also I'm not getting any compiler errors or warnings.

Comment: Your main remaining problem is trying to compare pointers to chars -- makes no sense and should give you a compiler warning.